# Springboot batch parallel processing (Using annotation)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, parallel-processing, spring-batch

I want to process millions of records and currently I am using in spring boot batch. Which is working fine with single thread, but I want to increase the speed of whole process by implementing parallel processing. Is this achievable without changing the reading & writing order?

Eg:

Assume I will be providing input text file 1000 student details where student number starts from 1 to 1000. I want to introduce parallel process creating 10 threads (100 students for each thread) and do some operation. Once all students are processed I should produce the text file output based on the input file.

Here output file also needs to follow same order, student number from 1 to 1000 though it uses multiple threads simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess all keys and create a HashMap (studentkey, studentResponse) and a Collection (ArrayList (studentReponse)) in the order that you want to return them.  The student responses in the collection are the same studentResponse instances in the map.  Then make your parallel calls that will **update the contents** of the studentReponse instances in the map according to the key(s) that it is processing.  The collection will be updated too since it has the same instances.  Now process the collection to create your text file.